# How to change route of jhipster microservice

Tags: jhipster

I developed a microservice application with these :

- Jhipster registry
- Uaa
- Gateway
- Microservice1

I want to deploy this in production on different server, but I don't want to use IP to access to microservices.

How can I launch microservice1 and uaa to say to the registry that they need to be called with these URLs :

- uaa.myapp.com
- microservice1.myapp.com